# using if else function in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataset called `brmayors`. Within this dataset, there is a variable called `DESCRICAO_GRAU_INSTRUCAO`.

I want to create a **new** variable called `collegedegree`, which is **yes** when the variable `DESCRICAO_GRAU_INSTRUCAO` shows `SUPERIOR COMPLETO` and **no** otherwise.

To create this new variable, I am trying to run `brmayors$collegedegree <- ifelse(brmayors$DESCRICAO_GRAU_INSTRUCAO == "SUPERIOR COMPLETO")`

I am trying to use function `ifelse` but I do not know how to manage it.

Could someone please help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base R`, we can do this without any `if/else` or `ifelse`

```
brmayors$collegedegree <-  c("no", "yes")[1+ 
    (brmayors$DESCRICAO_GRAU_INSTRUCAO == "SUPERIOR COMPLETO")]
```

Also, it is better to keep as `logical` instead of `yes/no` because filtering is much easier with that

```
brmayors$collegedegree <- brmayors$DESCRICAO_GRAU_INSTRUCAO == "SUPERIOR COMPLETO"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifelse` like :

```
brmayors$collegedegree <- ifelse(brmayors$DESCRICAO_GRAU_INSTRUCAO == "SUPERIOR COMPLETO", "yes", "no")
```

Or with case_when from `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
brmayors %>%
   mutate(collegedegree = 
         case_when(DESCRICAO_GRAU_INSTRUCAO == "SUPERIOR COMPLETO" ~ 'yes', 
         TRUE~'no'))
```